# How is it possible that Python's itertools.count does not increase?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a code that spins off new multiprocessing `Process`-es, giving them a serialized name using `itertools.count` to auto-increment the serial.

This is a glimpse of the code:

```
class WorkerStation(object):

    def __init__(self, basename, factory):
        # factory is a subclass of multiprocessing.Process
        self.basename = basename
        self.factory = factory
        self.serie = itertools.count(start=1)
        self.workers = []

    def launch_workers(want_count):
        while _count_active() < want_count:
            name = '{0}-{1}'.format(self.basename, self.serie.next())
            new_worker = self.factory(name=name)
            new_worker.start()
            print('Launched ', name)
            self.workers.append(new_worker)

    def _count_active():
        # It is possible as we spun off new workers, some earlier workers 
        # have terminated. The is_alive() also join() these deceased
        # workers.
        self.workers = [w for w in self.workers if w.is_alive()]
        return len(self.workers)
```

Now if I instantiate the `WorkerStation` for the first time, e.g.:

```
station_1 = WorkerStation(basename="st1", factory=WorkerClassOne)
station_1.launch_workers(want_count=5)
```

I can see the `serie` to be increasing properly, i.e., I'll see `Launched st1-1` up to `Launched st1-5`

But interestingly, the second time I instantiate this class:

```
station_2 = WorkerStation(basename="st2", factory=WorkerClassTwo)
station_2.launch_workers(want_count=2)
```

I'll see `serie` no longer incrementing, i.e., I'll see TWO lines of `Launched st2-1`.

How is this possible? How could `itertools.count` work for the first instantiaton, but no longer work for the second?

Comment: If you could provide a minimal example of the problem(i.e: One that is possible to copy/paste and debug) it would be much easier to answer your question.

Comment: Have you tried creating your own "counting" generator function?

Comment: @Governa unfortunately, it's part of a complex package. I've tried extracting the relevant parts above. I can ascertain, though, that the property used to store the `itertools.count` object is uniquely-named (`serie`) throughout the project.

Comment: @tobias_k I finally used a simplistic `self.serie = 0` and `self.serie += 1` where possible... and finally found out where I had gone wrong. Duh! Write-up to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Okay folks, it's apparently a mistake in the code.

I'll paste here (part of) two methods whose interaction caused this grief:

```
    def maintain_flights(self, target=None, force=False):
        # If target not specified, invoke the auto_count() method to automatically
        # determine the number of workers needed.
        target = target or self.auto_count()
        ... lots of code removed ...

    def rewind(self):
        self.maintain_flights(target=0, force=True)
        self.serie = itertools.count(start=1)
```

The main part of the program, during certain stages, will invoke the `.rewind()` method to reduce the number of workers to 0.

As you can see, invoking the method with `target=0` will cause the left side of the `target or self.auto_count()` expression to be false, resulting the code to invoke the `self.auto_count()` method.

So, instead of ending with zero workers, I got 1 worker.

Afterwards, the `self.serie` object got 'reset' to start counting at 1.

A bit later in the main code, the main code asks for 2 workers. It already got 1 worker from the botched `rewind()` attempt, and it added the second worker with `serie` again starting from 1.

I've replaced the offending code with this line:

```
target = target if target is not None else self.auto_count()
```

And now it works splendidly!

Thanks for the assistance, and apologies if I've sent you all on a wild goose-chase.